# SQL For Counting Passive Subscribers Between Given Dates

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I've worked all night to finish statistics part of a project I'm working on. One part of this statistics part is to show admins which subscribers didn't renew subscriptions between given dates.

**TABLES**

```
- members -
id (int)
hasSubscription (enum 1,0)

- subscriptions -
id (int)
member_id (int)
endDate (date)
active (enum 1,0)
```

**Example**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN subscriptions as s ON s.member_id = m.id
WHERE
s.endDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
s.active = 0
m.hasSubscription = 1
```

Normally that's how I could count members who has subscriptions and their subscription finished between given 2 dates.

What I'm after is to have number of members who have subscription which ended between given 2 dates but has no more active subscriptions.

At this point I can't think straight anymore. I will be really glad if you could help me out.

Comment: Can't you simply use the hasSubscription field to limit your query to members without any subscriptions? Or does that field not work that way?

Comment: hasSubscription is used just for if a member ever had a subscription or not. It is not used for if there is an active subscription or not. Thinking about it again (didn't sleep much lately) maybe it would be best to add another field to determine if member has active subscription or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM    members as m 
        INNER JOIN subscriptions AS s 
            ON s.member_id = m.id
WHERE   s.endDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
AND     s.active = 0
AND     m.hasSubscription = 1
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Subscriptions a
            WHERE   a.MemberID = m.ID
            AND     a.Active = 1
        )
```

Comment: Thanks **NOT EXISTS**... that's what I was after (:

Comment: It is worth checking the performance of this versus the LEFT JOIN equivalent.  MySQL generally does a better job of optimising a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know how the execution plans vary with these two queries. From past experience this version with the LEFT JOIN should be more efficient -

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM    members as m 
INNER JOIN subscriptions AS s 
    ON s.member_id = m.id
    AND s.endDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-02-01'
    AND s.active = 0
LEFT JOIN subscriptions a
    ON a.member_id = m.id
    AND s.endDate < a.endDate
    AND a.active = 1
WHERE m.hasSubscription = 1
AND a.member_id IS NULL
```